# Qual a maneira elegante para se ler esse Objeto PHP?

Tags: php, array, classes

Tenho o `Result` de um `Webservice` abaixo, estou fazendo uns "foreachs" para ler cada nível da Classe, mas penso que deve ter um maneira mais elegante de ler e obter os valores do objeto, segue o `Result`:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Codigo] => 1-0-21
    [Descricao] => REGIONAL DDD21
    [DddArray] => stdClass Object
        (
            [string] => 21
        )

    [Valores] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Valor] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ValorFace] => 1000
                            [ValorBonus] => 0
                            [Produto] => RECARGA CELULAR
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ValorFace] => 1500
                            [ValorBonus] => 0
                            [Produto] => RECARGA CELULAR
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ValorFace] => 2000
                            [ValorBonus] => 0
                            [Produto] => RECARGA CELULAR
                        )


                )

        )

)
```

Esse texto é o resultado da função:

```
$res = $client->RetornaRegionaisPorOperadoraDdd($params);
```

A maneira que estou fazendo é muito "POG":

```
foreach ($res as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $keyopera => $valopera){
        print_r($valopera);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não há nada de errado no que apresentou. Nem dá para dizer que é um pog.. rsrs ..

Comment: POG é Programação Orientada a Gambarra. `Foreach` é uma maneira elegante.

Comment: Uma Gambiarra pode conter um forEach()  normalmente e continuar sendo gambiarra.

Comment: Sim, o jeito que ele fez foi Vida Loka.

Comment: Isso não gerou erro? se você esta iterando `$res`, `$key` poderia ser `Codigo`, ai `$value` não serie um array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A forma mais simples é indicar qual chave quer iterar, dessa forma elemina o segundo foreach.

```
$res = $client->RetornaRegionaisPorOperadoraDdd($params);
foreach ($res->valores->valor as $item){
   echo $item['Produto'] .' - '. $item['ValorFace'];
}
```

Comment: Matou a pau rray, veja como ficou 

`foreach ($res->RetornaRegionaisPorOperadoraDddResult->Regional->Valores->Valor as $item){
 echo $item->Produto .' - '. $item->ValorFace;
}`